# How to identify Bloomberg bond tickers in Excel?

Tags: excel, bloomberg

In order to get Bloomberg bond tickers in Excel, for use with the API, I have been copying these from the Terminal. (Specifically, I am looking at US Treasury Notes.)

However, I would like to find a way to automatically or programmatically select / identify bond tickers in Excel, without having to manually copy from Bloomberg terminal every time.

Is there any way to do this using the Excel API or other API scripts?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but a question about using (or the functionality of) the Bloomberg add-in in Excel...

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this:

1) The old / pure Excel approach is to use the `BOND_CHAIN` field - in Excel, that is:

```
=BDS("ticker Corp", "BOND_CHAIN")
```

If you look in the Terminal, `FLDS BOND_CHAIN` (ensure Filter = 'ALL') will show you a number of additional overrides that you can use to set a maturity range etc.

However, the bad news about this approach is that it doesn't support non `Corp` tickers. That is fine for, say, Gilts, because you can use `UKT Corp` to get the gilts. But it doesn't work for US Treasuries, because there are both `T Corp` (AT&T) and `T Govt` (Treasuries).

2) The newer approach, which interacts with your terminal settings, is to use `SRCH` / `BSRCH`. You need to set up / save a search via `SRCH` in the terminal. You can then call the selection from this `SRCH` in Excel using:

```
=BSRCH("FI:search name")
```

Comment: It may be helpful to someone else to add that the second approach is available through the D-API (either Excel or programmatic APIs), but not through the server APIs (e.g. B-PIPE) - this is because it requires settings from a user's Terminal.